# How to Unit/Integrate Test Views to detect breaking changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, tdd, automated-tests

I have just started learning asp.net mvc and one reason of the primary reasons has been to move to TDD.

I am writing a small dashboard application which has reports. In this app, I had a primary controller called ReportsController, which right now has just one method, GetReport that takes in a query and returns a view if the query meets certain conditions, else returns an error message.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetReport(string query)
{    
    //calls the QueueRep and gets back DataTable
    ReportQuery reportQuery = new ReportQuery(query);
    if (reportQuery.IsValidQuery)
    {
        queryRepository.ExecuteReportQuery(ref reportQuery);                
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error");
    }           
    ViewData.Add("ResultDataTable",reportQuery.ResultDataTable);

    return View();
```

}

I had written 2 unit tests for this as follows

```
public void GetReport_Should_Return_Error_View_For_Malicious_Query()
{
    //Arrange
    string query = "drop table userInfo";
    var controller = CreateReportsController(query);

    //Act
    var result = controller.GetReport(query) as ViewResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(result.ViewName, "Error");

}

[Test]
public void GetReport_Should_Return_View_With_DataTable_For_Correct_Query()
{
    //Arrange
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("SELECT Year(CreatedOn) as Year, Month(CreatedOn) as Month, Count(CREATEDON) as NewEmployers");
    sb.Append("FROM dbo.UserInfo WHERE DefaultPurpose = 1 GROUP BY Year(CreatedOn), Month(CreatedOn)");

    string query = sb.ToString();

    var controller = CreateReportsController(query);

    //Act

    var result = controller.GetReport(query) as ViewResult;

    //Assert

    Assert.IsTrue(result.ViewData.ContainsKey("ResultDataTable"));
    Assert.IsTrue(result.ViewData["ResultDataTable"].GetType() == typeof(System.Data.DataTable));

}
```

Now, due to conflict with SSRS, the server/Reports was pointing to SSRS instead of Reports controller so I changed name of ReportsController to MyReportsController. I used refactor for the name change and changed my unit tests in the test project as well and ran the unit tests. Everything is fine.

But now when I ran actual app, I got an error. Basically, the folder name of the views had to be changed from Reports to MyReports. How can I test these kind of scenarios. Is only using functional testing tools like selenium? Or I could have written my tests differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything you should/could do to test this with unit tests, but integration tests with Selenium is a good way to go about it:

http://seleniumtoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, manual testing or functional test tools like Selenium are the only way to find these breaking changes.

The reason is because with unit testing you are only testing small bite sized parts of your code. So testing a controller's action method is great! In that test you need to remember that your testing your own code and not the asp.net and/or mvc frameworks. Now, to -render- a view result, this is handled outside of your action method. Secondly, we assume that the rendering logic (how to render) has been tested by Microsoft so we don't want waste time testing that either.

So this means we need to join independent modules together in a single test. When we have 2+ modules or areas etc to test, we suddenly jump out of unit testing and into manual or functional testing.